# esapi validator regex issue with "&sub"

Tags: java, regex, esapi

Im encountering a strange issue using esapi validation.

Bellow is my regex that is working for me as expected except when I include the string "&sub" it does not find a match.

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z :;=@$?()+&\\[\\]\\/\\\\#.,\\-'_]{0,1000}$
```

Any other combination like "&su" or "&bus" is fine, when I add "&sub anywhere in the string it throws an error.

```
Invalid input. Please conform to regex ^[0-9a-zA-Z :;=@$?()+\&\[\]\/\\#.,\-'_]{0,1000}$ with a maximum length of 1000
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: The error part sounds strange; if the regex doesn't match, then it should just fail and your code continues.  Can you show us your actual Java code?

Comment: by any chance do you have the `"` infront of the `&sub` as given in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, it doesn't like HTML special characters, others like &nbsp reproduce. Thanks